# Error when install Odoo15: directory not writable

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I just installed odoo15, but when I tried to start it, I get "Internal Error Message", and I get the follwing message from log file:

```
return self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1464, in dispatch
explicit_session = self.setup_session(httprequest)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1345, in setup_session
session_gc(self.session_store)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 26, in __get__
value = self.fget(obj)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1291, in session_store
path = odoo.tools.config.session_dir
File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/config.py", line 714, in session_dir
assert os.access(d, os.W_OK), \
AssertionError: /var/lib/odoo/sessions: directory is not writable - - -
```

How to fix this issues please

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you start odoo with the user that is able to write in this directory.

My guess is that /var/lib/odoo/sessions is only writable by root.
Did you create a new user for odoo?

Try this (with odoo:odoo being the user and the group of your odoo system user):

```
sudo chown -R odoo:odoo /var/lib/odoo
```

Otherwise make also sure it IS writable:

```
sudo chmod +w /var/lib/odoo/sessions
```

Comment: Hi Johnny,
It works, thank you so much

Comment: Can you mark it as answer and upvote my post? Thank you.

Comment: sure, thanks again, and have a nice day

Comment: I'm using docker so this shouldn't be an issue, but it still is.